# Mininet Routing not working

Tags: linux, networking, mininet, sdn

I have a problem with Mininet topology. I am trying to make a ping between **h3** and **h4**. They are connected to same switch **s4**. But they can not ping, they are in different subnet, so i am trying to make a **flow table for s4** but with no success.
Here is image of my topology :

[image]

after running Mininet I set up this:

```
h3 route add default gw 30.0.0.254 h3-eth0
h3 arp -s 30.0.0.254 00:00:00:00:33:33
h4 route add default gw 40.0.0.254 h4-eth0
h4 arp -s 40.0.0.254 00:00:00:00:44:44
```

Then I populate **s4 flow table**

```
table=0,ip,nw_src=30.0.0.3,actions=resubmit(,1)
table=0,ip,nw_src=40.0.0.4,actions=resubmit(,1)
table=0,icmp,nw_src=30.0.0.3,actions=resubmit(,1)
table=0,icmp,nw_src=40.0.0.4,actions=resubmit(,1)

table=1,ip,nw_dst=30.0.0.3,actions=mod_dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:03,output:1
table=1,ip,nw_dst=40.0.0.4,actions=mod_dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:04,output:2

table=1,priority=0,arp,nw_dst=30.0.0.3,actions=output:1
table=1,priority=0,arp,nw_dst=40.0.0.4,actions=output:2
```

when I run ping between **h3 and h4** and display **s4 dump-flow** I am getting this

```
 table=0, n_packets=1, n_bytes=98, idle_age=6, ip,nw_src=30.0.0.3 actions=resubmit(,1)
 table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, idle_age=17, ip,nw_src=40.0.0.4 actions=resubmit(,1)
 table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, idle_age=17, icmp,nw_src=30.0.0.3 actions=resubmit(,1)
 table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, idle_age=17, icmp,nw_src=40.0.0.4 actions=resubmit(,1)
 table=1, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, idle_age=17, ip,nw_dst=30.0.0.3 actions=mod_dl_dst:00:00:00:00:00:03,output:1
 table=1, n_packets=1, n_bytes=98, idle_age=6, ip,nw_dst=40.0.0.4 actions=mod_dl_dst:00:00:00:00:00:04,output:2
 table=1, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, idle_age=17, priority=0,arp,arp_tpa=30.0.0.3 actions=output:1
 table=1, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, idle_age=17, priority=0,arp,arp_tpa=40.0.0.4 actions=output:2
```

and Mininet is saying only this:

```
mininet> h3 ping h4 -c1
PING 40.0.0.4 (40.0.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 40.0.0.4 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Could you help me please how to make connectivity? Or what is wrong in flow table on s4? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Wireshark and use the command `s4 Wireshark` to observe the packets between the switch and the hosts. Check if the destination mac address of the packet has properly changed.